# no file in the directory

Tags: command-line, permissions

i just started using unix for my university (i have 0 prior knowledge on programming so bear with me if isay something stupid) and it wont find my file this is what i did so far:

- `nano (filename).sh`
- in the file i just wrote

  ```
  #!/bin/bash echo "hello world"
  ```

then saved and exited

- on the main page (not sure what its called) i wrote `chmod 755 (file name)` to give myself permissions
- typed `ls -1` and same my file name highlighed in green
- then `./(filename).sh` however it says theres no file even though when i type in `nano (filename).sh` it takes me to my file

i just wanted help with this its all confusing were learnig so many languages at once its hard to keep up. thank you for any help and advice!!

edit: this is the code

```
nano Ozzy.sh                                                                   
sysadmin@localhost:~$ ./Ozzy.sh                                                
/bin/bash: echo"hello world": No such file or directory                         
sysadmin@localhost:~$ nano Ozzy.sh                                             
sysadmin@localhost:~$ ./Ozzy.sh                                                
sysadmin@localhost:~$ chmod 755 Ozzy.sh                                        
sysadmin@localhost:~$ nano Ozzy.sh                                             
sysadmin@localhost:~$ ^C                                                        
sysadmin@localhost:~$
```

and this is the code in my file:

```
#!/bin/bash echo "hello world"
```

Comment: *"it says theres no file"* what **exactly** is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please give us exact details. Here is my best attempt at following what you wrote:

```
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ nano ozzy.sh
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug 31 Oct 19 13:30 ozzy.sh
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ chmod 755 ozzy.sh
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ cat ozzy.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 doug doug 31 Oct 19 13:30 ozzy.sh
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ ./ozzy.sh
hello world
doug@s19:~/ozzy$
```

EDIT: Based on the edit of your question:

```
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ ./ozzy.sh
/bin/bash: echo "hello world": No such file or directory
doug@s19:~/ozzy$ cat ozzy.sh
#!/bin/bash echo "hello world"
doug@s19:~/ozzy$
```

So your issue is that you need to have your `echo` line on its own line by itself, not on the shebang line.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! i added an edit for some clarification

Comment: No, the issue seem to be **no space** between `echo` and `"hello world"`

Comment: @raj : I tried that, but it gives a different error. I have edited my edit. Before your edit to the question it read as all one line.

Comment: I checked - you're right! But as in the error message he quoted there is no space, it seems he did that mistake too.

Comment: @raj : Agreed..

Comment: hey doug thank you having it on its own line seemed to work. do i write my code in my file then in the main page use ./(filename).sh to run the script? again thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Ozzy : For what you posted, in the terminal window you would run `./Ozzy.sh` similar to what I showed in my answer, except that I use a lower case "o" for "ozzy", and case matters in linux.

Comment: genuinely bro thank you you acc helped me alot